# How to write content by calling WriteHtml() function twice at a same file using mpdf library in PHP 7?

Tags: php, php-7, mpdf

I wanna write a table with the records from my database into PDF using mpdf. But when i retrieve the records using while loop my table header takes the effect, the records doing loop as well as table header because the "WriteHtml()" function inside the loop.

I've tried to solve this problem by calling "WriteHtml()" twice, which means to write the table header and content separtely, but the mpdf produces a blank page PDF file.

```
$html = "<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>NAMA</th>
 <th>PEKERJAAN</th>
 <th>ALAMAT</th>
 <th>SUKU</th>
</tr>";

$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($html),\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::DEFAULT_MODE, true, false);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_query)) {
$html2 = "<tr>
 <td align='center'>".htmlspecialchars($id++)."</td>
 <td align='center'>".htmlspecialchars($data['nama'])."</td>
 <td align='center'>".htmlspecialchars($data['pekerjaan'])."</td>
 <td align='center'>".htmlspecialchars($data['alamat'])."</td>
 <td align='center'>".htmlspecialchars($data['suku'])."</td>
</tr>
</table>";

$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($html2),\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::DEFAULT_MODE,false, true);
}

$mpdf->Output();
```

I expect the content of PDf file output is the table like my index.php like this:

https://photos.smugmug.com/Stackoverflow/i-26sKBgt/0/ed83bc1c/L/expect_output%20-%20Copy-L.png

instead of like this:

https://photos.smugmug.com/Stackoverflow/i-cVszxJW/0/af15bde0/L/unexpect_output%20-%20Copy-L.png

i am sorry i post a link because i am not being able to post image right now

Comment: You are closing the `</table>` every loop.

Comment: OMG haha. Thanks @FelippeDuarte